# Use inserted ids from Laravel and Dropzone image uploaded data

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone

I have a form with a Dropzone div, for massive image uploads with another data.

But, as the images are uploaded with ajax I need to know which Id's are assigned to those images.

The problem became when I save those ids in the session data. It just saves the first and the latest ids.

For example, when I submit 4 images it returns me the second and the last id.

My controller method (via Ajax):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $photos = $request->file('file');

        if (!is_array($photos))
            $photos = [$photos];

        if (!is_dir($this->photos_path))
            mkdir($this->photos_path, 0777);


        for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {

            $photo = $photos[$i];
            $name = sha1(date('YmdHis') . str_random(30));
            $save_name = $name . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $resize_name = $name . str_random(2) . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

            Image::make($photo)
                ->resize(250, null, function ($constraints) {
                    $constraints->aspectRatio();
                })
                ->save($this->photos_path . '/' . $resize_name);

            $photo->move($this->photos_path, $save_name);

            $upload = new UploadedImages();
            $upload->filename = $save_name;
            $upload->resized_name = $resize_name;
            $upload->original_name = basename($photo->getClientOriginalName());
            $upload->user_id = Auth::id();
            $upload->save();

            Session::push('uploaded_images_ids', $upload->id);
        }

        return Response::json(['message' => 'Image saved Successfully'], 200);
    }
```

Response with Debug bar (should response 4 ids, not 2):
[image: laravel debug bar]

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array to store your image and id

Here is the idea below

```
$image_array = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {
   ....
   array_push($image_array,['image_name' => $save_name, 'image_id' => $upload->id]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it has sense, but remember this method controller is called via ajax, so? I'm afraid that $image_array won't be visible to the main.

Comment: @ErichGarcía You can use your existing code. put Session::push outside the loop and set  Session::push('uploaded_images_ids', $image_array);

Comment: or use session::set()

Comment: Yes, it works! Note that I change too the Dropzone configuration to parallelUploads: 1